# In binomial regression, how do we know what is $m_i$ (number of trials in the binomial distribution)?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

I just fitted a glm with the binomial family in R and to my surprise I didn't need to specify the $m_i$ values. Checking my notes, we simply assumed that $Y =_d \text{Binom}(m_i, p_i)$ where $p_i = H(x_i^T \beta)$, and thus our predictions are $\mathbb{E}[Y|X_i] = m_i p_i$.

My response was binary to begin with, and to my surprise my fitted values are all in $[0,1]$. So, there must be an automatic way to select $m_i$, but how? I think $m_i$ are supposed to be known in advance, as for binomial distribution, re-writing it into the exponential family yields $b(\theta) = m_i log(1+e^{\theta})$, and we are supposed to know fully what $b$ is.

Comment: What command did you use? Do your data have $m_i=1$ for all $i$?

Comment: @Sycorax just glm(formula, 'binomial', data). The response variables are either 0 or 1 for this case, but what's stopping $m_i=2$ everywhere?

Comment: If you don't specify otherwise, it assumes your m's are all 1. The overwhelming majority of times people call a logistic regression routine, their data are individual Bernoullis (0/1) ... easily more than 90%. Indeed many people are unaware that you can do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what is happening. From [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/family):

> For the binomial and quasibinomial families the response can be specified in one of three ways:
>
> ...
>
> 2. As a numerical vector with values between 0 and 1, interpreted as the proportion of successful cases (with the total number of cases given by the weights)..."

where the `weights` default to 1. In other words, this is a "Bernoulli GLM" (as the Bernoulli distribution is a special case of the binomial distribution for $m=1$).

The kind of GLM that you describe, where $m_i$ is some positive integer, is the third case listed.

> 3. As a two-column integer matrix: the first column gives the number of successes and the second the number of failures.

so the response would have 2 columns, $y_i$ and $m_i - y_i$.